# Oracle Enterprise manager 13c Installation failed with gcc / glibc not found, even if they're installed in higher Versions

Tags: oracle-enterprise-manager

I try to install OEM 13c on Oracle Linux 7.9 in silent mode.
The response File is filled up
Installation failed with

> Checking for gcc-4.8.2-16; Not found.  Failed

Checking for glibc-devel-2.17-55-i686; Not found.      Failed

> 

but

> rpm -qa --queryformat "%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}(%{ARCH})\n" | grep glibc

glibc-2.17-326.0.9.el7_9(x86_64)

rpm -qa --queryformat "%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}(%{ARCH})\n" | grep gcc

libgcc-4.8.5-44.0.3.el7(x86_64)

> 

so higher versions are installed by default.

How can I proceed ?

I tried
-ignoreprereqs but this is not available for the installation routine, and
-ignoresysprereqs will also ends up in this error

This environments works fine for Oracle 19c Databases

Any suggestions?
thanks
Uwe

several installations with -ignoreprereqs or -ignoresysprereqs
on different Environments (Virtual or AWS)